# SQL; csv import with semicolons in data and double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wanting to import a CSV file which has some values as such:

```
123;456;"78;9";1011
```

Simply said, there are some quotes in a value, but the value is within double quotes. When I use a bulk import, the value '"78' is put into one column, whereas '9"' is put into the next column. How can I prevent this?

I am using below query:

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

I'm using SQL Server!
In a test environment i've setup the new sql server, and the fieldquote seems to be ignored in the statement, and the fields are still split up. What am I doing wrong? I'm doing:

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIELDQUOTE='"'
)
GO
```

Comment: Import how? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft SQL Server. I want to use a statement to import it, not the wizard!

Comment: SqlServer 2017 will fix it by setting [FIELDQUOTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the bulk import, this is per default character *"*

Comment: Unfortunately, the server does not have 2017 yet and a short term update isn't in the cards.

Comment: In that case, I would take the source and replace the semicolons with a different character in the text, or use a different separator

Comment: In a test environment i've setup the new sql server, and the fieldquote seems to be ignored in the statement, and the fields are still split up. What am I doing wrong? I'm doing the second statement in OP.